# How to force "Inbox", "Sent", and "Outbox" folders to be listed at the top of Outlook archive folders group (above subfolders)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, archiving

I have just enabled autoarchiving in Outlook 2010, but I've noticed that some subfolders in my archive PST are in a different order to my original PST file.

Specifically, the "Inbox", "Sent", and "Outbox" folders are no longer at the top, but instead alphabetically arranged.

The problem is that the majority of my emails are in the "Inbox" folder (rather than in other subfolders), so if this important folder hides half way down the folder list (instead of at the top) it makes it harder to reach it (I have hundreds of subfolders).

How can I force these special folders to be listed at the top of my archive folders group (essentially mirroring how they appear in the main PST file) so it is easier to find them?

Comment: This earnt me the "Tumbleweed" badge. Geez. Lucky me.